# Why are these default parameters defined as they are?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently learning Ruby and RoR and I stumbled across this declaration:

```
link_to_remote(name, options = {}, html_options = nil)
```

I discovered that this pattern is used on several other Rails functions.

Why are the default values defined that way? Why not one of these two?

```
... options = {}, html_options = {}) 
... options = nil, html_options = nil)
```

Is this some kind of convention I should follow in my own functions, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is defined like this:

```
link_to_function(name, remote_function(options), html_options || options.delete(:html))
```

This allows you to specify the `html_options` as part of the `options` hash instead of as a separate parameter. On the other hand, the `options` hash is always passed to `remote_function`, so we need it.

It's also a bit more efficient to use the singleton nil rather than construct an array that will never be used every time the method is called. I wouldn't say this reason is so compelling that I wouldn't use {} if it made the resulting code cleaner, but in the absence of any other consideration, it seems like the logical thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert on it, but for `options` it might be because the calling code uses the `merge` method to combine whatever you pass in with the assumed defaults; setting it to `nil` would just remove all of the options.  I'm not sure about `html_options`, but it might be something similar to that.

`html_options` might call a block and have something defined to check if it's given a hash or not.  Like I said I'm not an expert but that might be why.  I just checked on an Ubuntu VM and according to irb, an empty hash evaluates to `true` so that might be why.  The calling code probably uses a block with something line:

```
if html_options
    # do stuff
end
```

so it's `nil` by default because the code would execute and probably give you a nil error with an empty Hash